# Designing a Java Generic Hierarchy to avoid Template Class Conflict

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, collections

Consider a Java generic class hierarchy of the following rawtype form.

```
class A ...
class B extends A ...
class C extends A ...
```

With a method in class A and overridden in B and C.

```
String foo() ...
String bar(A a) ...
```

We can make the following calls successfully.

```
String r = (new B()).foo();
String r = (new B()).bar(new C());
```

The real goal here is to save instances of A in a container 
and process them all without regard for which sort of A we have.

```
A fred;
List as = new LinkedList();
for (A a : as) ... fred.bar(a); ...
```

Objects of classes B and C can be constructed and passed to foo with no problem.
Now we introduce generics.

```
class A<T,U,V> ...
class B<T> extends A<T,Void,Object> ...
class C<N> extends A<String,Void,Object> ...
```

With a method in class A and overridden in B and C.

```
T foo() ...
```

Then we make the following reasonable calls.

```
String r = (new A<String,Void,Object>()).foo();
String r = (new B<String>()).foo();
String r = (new C<Integer>()).foo();

String r = (new B<String>()).foo();
String r = (new B<String>()).bar(new C<Integer>());
```

The real goal here is to save instances of A in a container 
and process them all without regard for which sort of A we have.

```
A<String,String,Integer> fred;
List<A<String,String,Integer>> as = new LinkedList<>();
for (A a : as) ... fred.bar(a); ...
```

These decisions makes it impossible to load objects of types B and C into the "as" list,
due to conflicting types in the generic template.

Note this is endemic an existing piece of software for which I am trying to clear up warning.

Comment: `List<String,String,Integer> as` is invalid. List has only one type parameter. Did you mean `List<A<String,String,Integer>> as`?

Comment: @user7 yes, that is what I meant. I can give specific code examples, but here is a link to the actual system and an example file. https://github.com/babeloff/fql/blob/master/src/catdata/aql/exp/InstExp.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about the return value of `foo()`, then you could use this:

```
List<A<String, ?, ?>> as = ...;
```

That will let you store `A` or any subtype of `A` for which the type argument to `T` is `String`, but with anything for `U` and `V`. So:

```
as.add(new A<String, String, Integer>()); // fine
as.add(new B<String>()); // fine
as.add(new C<Integer>()); // fine

as.add(new A<Double, String, Integer>()); // won't compile
```

However, you won't be able to call methods of `A` which have parameters of type `U` and `V`. If that's a problem, then it seems like you have to redesign somehow.

Possibly also see:

- [*Wildcards* Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)
- [*Guidelines for Wildcard Use*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html)
- [*What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: I found the links provided most helpful.